# How do i use firebase realtime database and firestore together in one app in angular

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am setting up a new project on angular using firebase. After certain period of time I realise I need the firestore also included into my project. Now the problem is that how do I configure that in one application in angular so that I can use firebase realtime database and firestore together.

This is my firebase realtime database configuration in angular -

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: "apikey",
    authDomain: "friendlyeats-3f66a.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://friendlyeats-3f66a.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "friendlyeats-3f66a",
    storageBucket: "friendlyeats-3f66a.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:web:546e663bfcf9179d"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you from using Cloud Firestore and Realtime Database in the same application, in the same project.  Nothing special needs to be configured for that.  Just use each SDK as you would normally.

Comment: ok once i used each sdk but how do i configure the firestore.
suppose on our app.module.ts file we configure the database like
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.configuration) but how  i configure the other database into that. i need help on that.

Answer (score 1):

You just once init `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(envi)` then u just import modules like for real time database: `AngularFireDatabaseModule` Cloud store: `AngularFirestoreModule` Auth: `AngularFireAuthModule` or functions: `AngularFireFunctionsModule`

```
imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireFunctionsModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
  ],
```